# How to make a menu without androidx

Tags: java, android, androidx

I want to make an options menu in an android app, but without using androidx. 
All the solutions I found online are using androidx, but I can't since my phone only has Android 8.0. Do you have any tips? Thanks!

Comment: AndroidX is a support library, it does not require an Android version of 8.0 oder higher.

Comment: androidx is the new name for appcompat libraries. The components from these are bundled with your app instead of relying on being a part of system libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AndroidX is simply a new component from Jetpack as an improvement/replacement to support libraries, however, any androidX code you find will still be valid for your device. https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx?gclid=CjwKCAjwscDpBRBnEiwAnQ0HQL5f_RWMhE9bqJUtqvDQSenu7rDQIQRnLpZ_Bp_zJGDNNF0XYejCkRoCDKQQAvD_BwE

Comment: Thank you! But it says on the site you linked: "If you want to use AndroidX in a new project, you need to set the compile SDK to Android 9.0 (API level 28) or higher [...]"

Comment: @fuxibut There is a difference between the _**compileSdkVersion**_ and _**minSdkVersion**_. The first one is the one that the app is compiled with and the second points the oldest version of android on which the app is supported. Even if you have an Android 8 phone you can still install it.